# Not able to apply allignment for Controls in MVC Razor view using Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Problem Statement:**

In one of my edit view I want make textbox as disabled, so for this i'm using **DisplayFor** instead of **TextboxFor**. But when I use Displayfor, alignment is not coming properly. You can see images attached for your reference. I'm using **Bootstrap CSS 3.0**

*Any help would be appreciated. What inline CSS I should use to align properly??*

**Image1:** In this image you can see that Acquire Status ID label and **Textboxfor** properly aligned.
[image]

**Image2:** When I use DisplayFor instead of Textboxfor, Acquire Status ID label and Displayfor are not aligned properly.

[image]

**View:**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AcquirestatusID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AcquirestatusID,new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AcquirestatusID)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: show the html markup also instead of razor view

Comment: Try using TextBoxFor and adding a new { disabled = "disabled" } parameter

Comment: @Bardo-Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I solved my problem using readonly attribute to my Textboxfor.***

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AccessoriesID,new { @class = "form-control",@readonly="readonly" })
```

***After applying above line of code my edit view looks:***

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It might be happening due to the style.css which is by default in your project.

**Remove style.css from the project**

**Note:** you might only need some of the validation classes inside it

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [csoueidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850713/csoueidi) , check with developer tools on IE or inspect element on chrome to see which css is loading the styles for that textbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to line up the text and not use a textbox, use the class "form-control-static"

```
<div class="col-md-10 form-control-static">@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.AcquirestatusID)</div>
```